# bashrc doesn't identify the java home

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu

I had installed java in ubuntu
but when I set the java home in ~/.bashrc
the command doesn't work
I had used these commands in ~/.bashrc
using this command

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

# JAVA HOME directory setup

export JAVA_HOME =usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111
set PATH = $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

after that every time I open a terminal 
this message shows to me

> bash: export: `=usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111': not a valid identifier

Comment: Remove the space between JAVA_HOME and =

Comment: Also not sure  if it is a typo or not, the start of the `JAVA_HOME` should have the `/` i.e. `/usr/java..` . Do re-check your path.

Comment: `set` is not used for variable assignment; it is used to set the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc).

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to edit `.bashrc` in ***your*** home directory. If you do, the ownership of that file is probably fubar

Answer (score 2):

You should assign variables with no spaces. And it is better to quote strings in bash.

```
export JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use spaces in the variable assignment.

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

# JAVA HOME directory setup

export JAVA_HOME=usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the spaces between variable assignments and recommend double-quoting the values assigned to avoid word-splitting done by shell.

```
export JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Do re-check your `JAVA_HOME` path, if it should start with a `/`, since you were missing it as part of the question. The below might have been your actual path.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_111"
```